# Cooling fan on Lenovo laptop runs fast when CPU load is low

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, fan, lenovo-laptop

Ubuntu 16.04 on an Lenovo Ideapad 320s-15IKB ([link to manual in several languages](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320s-15ikb/documentation)) worked well until two weeks ago. Now the cooling fan isn't working properly, randomly changing speed from slow to fast in a matter of seconds.

System monitor shows CPU usage is low, but the fan is at high speed. Usually it turned ON when I used multiple heavy programs, or when the RAM is almost full...

I have this laptop since January so it is relatively new; is this normal behavior?

Comment: It's a good idea to install a temperature graphing program that tracks several or all of the temp sensors in the laptop.  You can see the temp spikes, relate them to opening / running programs, and see the results of changes to pwmconfig or whichever fan control program you use.

Comment: Have you cleaned the dust out of your device?  Based on the description of heavy usage, the fan running at full speed sounds like intended behavior, I would reduce your usage if it bothers you.

Comment: You may find https://openhardwaremonitor.org/ useful in this regard; yes, it's available for both Ubuntu Linux and Windows as well as other Linux distros.